# Unable to Connect to AWS RDS with Podman Compose, but Works with Docker Compose

Tags: docker, devops, podman, podman-compose

I have a setup where I've deployed frontend and backend images on an AWS EC2 machine using Docker and Docker Compose. Recently, I decided to migrate from Docker to Podman for container management. However, after migrating to Podman, I'm facing connectivity issues with AWS RDS.

Here's a brief overview of my setup:

I have frontend and backend Docker images deployed on an AWS EC2 machine.
These images are managed using Docker Compose.
The backend service needs to connect to an AWS RDS instance for database operations.
Everything works fine with Docker Compose, but after switching to Podman Compose, the backend service is unable to connect to the AWS RDS instance.
Here are the key points:

Issue: Unable to connect to AWS RDS from backend service deployed with Podman Compose.
Context: Successfully connected to AWS RDS when using Docker Compose.
Setup: Images deployed on an AWS EC2 machine.
Backend: Needs to connect to AWS RDS for database operations.
Investigation: Checked network configurations, AWS RDS settings, and environment variables but couldn't find any issues.
Any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this connectivity issue with Podman Compose would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you connect to anything over the network from that container? Exactly how does the failure happen? There aren't any details here to work with.